# Querying the database with a variable passed as an argument in SQLite android

Tags: android, database, sqlite, parameter-passing

I am creating an app Where the user can search database with inputs provided by user through edittext boxes.I am passing them to the database file as string argument to query and I am getting error.attaching the code

This is the button click listener and autoname is Autotextview

```
 b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
 @Override
 public void onClick(View v) {

 MyDatabase m =new MyDatabase(getActivity());
 Cursor c=m.searchname(autoname.getText().toString());

 simpleCursorAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(getActivity(),     R.layout.custom_layout_row, c,
                    new String[]{"_id", "name", "phone", "email", "subject"},
                    new int[]{R.id.rownumber, R.id.rowname, R.id.rowphone, R.id.rowmail, R.id.rowsubject}, 0);
            listView.setAdapter(simpleCursorAdapter);


        }
    });
```

This is the code in Mydatabase.java(Database file)

```
    public Cursor searchname(String argument) {
    Cursor cursor = null;
    cursor = s.query("student", null, "name=?", new String[]{argument}, null, null, null);


    return cursor;
    }
```

I am getting error in the query string

if i run raw query

```
Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("select * from student where name =?", new String[]{argument});
```

i got this error:

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method
>   'android.database.Cursor
>   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQuery(java.lang.String,
>   java.lang.String[])' on a null object reference at
>   com.techpalle.miniproject.MyDatabase.searchname(MyDatabase.java:107)
>   at
>   com.techpalle.miniproject.SearchFragment$2.onClick(SearchFragment.java:71)

Comment: Can you try running raw query Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("select * from  student where name =?", new String[]{argument});

Comment: It is also giving error.

Comment: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.database.Cursor android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQuery(java.lang.String, java.lang.String[])' on a null object reference
                                                                             at com.techpalle.miniproject.MyDatabase.searchname(MyDatabase.java:107)
                                                                             at com.techpalle.miniproject.SearchFragment$2.onClick(SearchFragment.java:71)

Comment: Can you post the error here please

Comment: Write SQLiteDatabase s = this.getWritableDatabase(); Cursor cursor = s.rawQuery("select * from student where name =?", new String[]{argument});

Comment: Try now :) Should work fine :) You should get the writable database reference before actually running the query :) You were missing it :)

Comment: Did that work or still facing issue ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error says you are trying to run rawQuery on a null object :)
That means your s is null :) You should get a writable database reference before you could execute any query on that :)

So you can try this :)

```
public Cursor searchname(String argument) {
     Cursor cursor = null;
     SQLiteDatabase s = this.getWritableDatabase(); 
     Cursor cursor = s.rawQuery("select * from student where name =?", new String[]{argument});
     return cursor;
}
```

Lemme know if you still have the issue :) Happy coding buddy :)

Comment: Thank you So much.It worked fine.

Comment: @Phillen Always welcome buddy :) Glad I could help :)

Comment: this.getWritableDatabase(); was also having trouble so used database helper object instead of this..and it worked. Thank you so much again

Comment: Isn't your Mydatabase.java extended SQLiteOpenHelper buddy ??? I usually extend my database files with SQLiteOpenHelper so I wrote this :) What was the issue with this.getWritableDatabase(); curious to know :)

Comment: getWritableDatabase was in red and clicking on it showed --cannot resolve method getwritabledatabase--  and I am a beginner so I don't know in depth.I haven't extended from SQLLiteOpenHelper. I have imported it.I will extend and let you know the results.

Comment: @Phillen If you extend you will have lot more things to tackle buddy :) If ok then dont extend on the other hand if you want to learn it completely here is atutorial you can make use of :) http://www.androidhive.info/2011/11/android-sqlite-database-tutorial/

Comment: I tried extending from the SQLiteOpenHelper and it asked me to changemy class to abstract.done it and it throwed red line on my default constructor saying there is no default constructor for the SQLiteOpenHelper Class.I am newbie so I think it will take a long time to figure what is wrong.

Comment: Thank you so much for the tutorial.Let me go through it.You are a Star.Thanks again.

Comment: @Phillen : did you read my previous comment buddy :) extending your data base classes is a good practice :) but when you do it you have to tackle few things :) Read the tutorial carefully :) learn it then you will understand what were you missing in your code :) Happy coding buddy :) and finally if its not too much to ask for, and if you are really happy with the answer, please accept it :) Happy coding :)